# Rails - Tagging with has_many through and select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, has-many-through

I'm implementing select2 tagging with a has_many through relationship. My implementation has 2 different scenarios.

1. The select menu allows multiple (tagging) but does not allow on the fly input into the select menu.
2. Same as above but uses ajax to allow the user to enter new select values on the fly.

Scenario 1 works well for tagging. Scenario 2 seems to work (can perform tagging) but does not save the values. My problem seems to come down to my my input elements for the scenarios.

**Scenario 1 uses:**

```
<%= f.association :repairers, label_method: :rep_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: true, label: 'Repairer'%>
```

and when the form is submitted gives params similar to:

`"repairer_ids"=>["", "1132", "1131"]`

**Scenario 2 uses:**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :repair_type_id, :class => "required on-the-fly-select select"%>
```

and uses a lot of js code to implement on the fly input for the select menu. When the form is submitted the data will look like:

`"repair_type_id"=>"5688,5690"`

So with scenario 2 the ids are not submitted as an array. I have tried changing the select to:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("repair_item[repair_type_ids][]", "", :id => "repair_item_repair_type_ids", :class => "required on-the-fly-select select") %>
```

but then the relevant param is submitted incorrectly and doesn't save:

`"repair_type_ids"=>["5688,5690"]`

Is it possible to get the params from **Scenario 2** to submit in the format that Rails made the params in **Scenario 1**?

Comment: why can't use `split` method of ruby to convert that data string into array and store into DB

Answer (score 0):

Try `String#split`

```
repair_type_id = "5688,5690"
repair_type_id.split(',')
=> ["5688", "5690"]
```

It's Better to use this `split` method in controller while saving the data on particular attribute for this instead of on `hidden_tag`.

**Edit:**

If you want to convert string in `plural` then use `pluralize` same as for `singularize`

```
2.0.0-p481 :010 > 'cat'.pluralize 
 => "cats" 
2.0.0-p481 :011 > 'dogs'.singularize
 => "dog"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are you able to comment why it's better to use  split rather than tinkering with the hidden_tag. I ask as from the sample code in my question we can see the repair_type param is returned as either a singular or plural (repair_type_ids). I would rather return it as a plural so I can have consistency in my controller. Is it possible to have my f.hidden_field submit with the plural param name?